# Centos has been hacked,how to find out the backdoor?

Tags: centos

[image]Thanks for come,first hope your guy pardon my English!

I hired a VPS,only use the pptpd server.Few days ago i ssh it and feel some thing wrong . type last command and get a error ,like direction or file had been moved .

`cat /var/log/secure` and got a lot ssh Failed massege ,but two or three "Accepted" I'm sure is not me. so I change password and check `/etc/passwd` and change sshd port to 1973. everything look like ok.

when type `netstat -anpt`, a progress name like rc.d/statd listen a port ,that is the leak been hacked?

Then I block every INPUT port exclude ssh=1973 and pptp=1723 but it seems not work right .

They still can ESTABLISHED connect and run command with out user
What am I going to do?

There is the information i get hope is useful

```
[root@US-seven ~]# netstat -anpt
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1973                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1578/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6662/pptpd          
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:56585               149.202.219.49:1520         TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0     48 VPS  IP:1973                my ip:47087                 ESTABLISHED 24672/sshd          
tcp        0      1 VPS  IP:57480               69.30.224.86:80             SYN_SENT    16610/sdpd          
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:55069               149.202.219.49:1520         ESTABLISHED 27236/ls -la        
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:1723                my ip:47689                 ESTABLISHED 26120/pptpd [59.53. 
tcp        0      1 127.0.1.1:43002             127.0.1.1:3306              SYN_SENT    16610/sdpd          
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:46561               158.69.219.235:80           TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 :::1973                     :::*                        LISTEN      1578/sshd           
[root@US-seven ~]# netstat -anpt
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1973                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1578/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6662/pptpd          
tcp        0      1 VPS  IP:57517               69.30.224.86:80             SYN_SENT    16610/sdpd          
tcp        0     96 VPS  IP:1973                my ip:47087                 ESTABLISHED 24672/sshd          
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:55069               149.202.219.49:1520         ESTABLISHED 27236/ls -la        
tcp        0      1 127.0.1.1:43036             127.0.1.1:3306              SYN_SENT    16610/sdpd          
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:1723                my ip:47689                 ESTABLISHED 26120/pptpd [59.53. 
tcp        0      0 :::1973                     :::*                        LISTEN      1578/sshd           
[root@US-seven ~]# skill -9 27236
[root@US-seven ~]# netstat -anpt
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1973                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1578/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6662/pptpd          
tcp        0      1 127.0.1.1:43051             127.0.1.1:3306              SYN_SENT    16610/sdpd          
tcp        0     48 VPS  IP:1973                my ip:47087                 ESTABLISHED 24672/sshd          
tcp        0    272 VPS  IP:34746               164.132.170.78:1520         ESTABLISHED 27888/pwd           
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:46611               158.69.219.235:80           ESTABLISHED 27888/pwd           
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:55069               149.202.219.49:1520         TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:34740               164.132.170.78:1520         ESTABLISHED 27886/sh            
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:1723                my ip:47689                 ESTABLISHED 26120/pptpd [59.53. 
tcp        0      1 VPS  IP:57533               69.30.224.86:80             SYN_SENT    16610/sdpd          
tcp        0      0 :::1973                     :::*                        LISTEN      1578/sshd           
[root@US-seven ~]# skill -9 27886
[root@US-seven ~]# skill -9 27888
[root@US-seven ~]# netstat -anpt
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1973                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1578/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6662/pptpd          
tcp        0     48 VPS  IP:1973                my ip:47087                 ESTABLISHED 24672/sshd          
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:55129               149.202.219.49:1520         TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:46611               158.69.219.235:80           TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      1 VPS  IP:57551               69.30.224.86:80             SYN_SENT    16610/sdpd          
tcp        0      1 127.0.1.1:43074             127.0.1.1:3306              SYN_SENT    16610/sdpd          
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:55069               149.202.219.49:1520         TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:34740               164.132.170.78:1520         TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:1723                my ip:47689                 ESTABLISHED 26120/pptpd [59.53. 
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:34764               164.132.170.78:1520         ESTABLISHED 28211/id            
tcp        0      0 :::1973                     :::*                        LISTEN      1578/sshd           
[root@US-seven ~]# netstat -anpt
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1973                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1578/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6662/pptpd          
tcp        0     48 VPS  IP:1973                my ip:47087                 ESTABLISHED 24672/sshd          
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:55129               149.202.219.49:1520         TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:46611               158.69.219.235:80           TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:55069               149.202.219.49:1520         TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:34740               164.132.170.78:1520         TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      1 VPS  IP:57562               69.30.224.86:80             SYN_SENT    16610/sdpd          
tcp        0      1 127.0.1.1:43083             127.0.1.1:3306              SYN_SENT    16610/sdpd          
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:1723                my ip:47689                 ESTABLISHED 26120/pptpd [59.53. 
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:34764               164.132.170.78:1520         ESTABLISHED 28211/id            
tcp        0      0 :::1973                     :::*                        LISTEN      1578/sshd           
[root@US-seven ~]# netstat -anpt
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1973                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1578/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1723                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      6662/pptpd          
tcp        0    240 VPS  IP:1973                my ip:47087                 ESTABLISHED 24672/sshd          
tcp        0      1 127.0.1.1:44133             127.0.1.1:3306              SYN_SENT    16610/sdpd          
tcp        0      1 VPS  IP:58614               69.30.224.86:80             SYN_SENT    16610/sdpd          
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:1723                my ip:47689                 ESTABLISHED 26120/pptpd [59.53. 
tcp        0      0 VPS  IP:34764               164.132.170.78:1520         ESTABLISHED 28211/id            
tcp        0      0 :::1973                     :::*                        LISTEN      1578/sshd
```

and there is some command is not me run:

```
root      2079     1  0 Aug23 ?        00:00:01 auditd
root      6662     1  0 Aug23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/pptpd
root      6728   467  0 Aug23 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/udevd -d
root     16610     1  0 Aug23 ?        00:04:57 /usr/sbin/sdpd  
root     24672  1578  0 13:21 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@pts/0 
root     24734 24672  0 13:21 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
root     26120  6662  0 13:25 ?        00:00:02 pptpd [my ip:CD78 - 0380]                                                                             
root     26121 26120  0 13:25 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/pppd local file /etc/ppp/options.pptpd 115200 192.168.0.1:172.24.24.100 ipparam my ip plugin
root     28211     1  0 13:30 ?        00:00:01 id                 
root     40702     1  0 14:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/acpid           
root     40705     1  0 14:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gnome-vfs-daemon
root     40709     1  0 14:02 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
root     40713     1  0 14:02 ?        00:00:00 klogd -x                  
root     40714     1  0 14:02 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
root     40722     1  0 14:02 ?        00:00:00 grep "A"                          
root     40724     1  0 14:02 ?        00:00:00 ifconfig                          
root     40727     1  0 14:02 ?        00:00:00 sh                          
root     40728     1  0 14:02 ?        00:00:00 cat resolv.conf                          
root     40729     1  0 14:02 ?        00:00:00 whoami                          
root     40730 24734  3 14:02 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple answer where the backdoor is, but you can find some information which can lead to closer identification.

**Fist:**

the best idea is to *drop the vps and deploy a new one*.

Processes run under root user and someone accessed as root (possible simly guess right your password), so:

- change root password (and use a strong one)
- change ssh key (remove all old/unknown keys from `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`)
- allow access to ssh from your IP only
- last but no least, update kernel (there can be a security problem).

Also check all users on the server and do the same.

Check, if any changes appear on rpm packages: `rpm -aV` - (it's a big problem if eg. `sshd` binary have different md5sum, permissions, etc. See VERIFY OPTIONS section of `man rpm` for more details).

**For identification:**

Instead of killing running processes try to investigate where they come from. You can start with `pstree`, which show you parent process. Eg. with `pstree -s -p <pid>`.

Some info you can find within `/proc/`. cat `/proc/<pid>/status` give you details. You can check used files by a process with `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd`, `ls -l /proc/<pid>cwd` shows you link to current working dir. Link to executable of process check with `ls -l /proc/<pid>/exe` and arguments with `cat /proc/<pid>/command`. There is more info you can find with `/proc/`, check [docs](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html) for details.

And be lucky :)

**For future:**

Disable root on ssh, access as a user and use `sudo` for switch to root. Block ssh from all IPs instead of your own and install and configure `fail2ban` for ssh to block incoming bots, who guesses passwords.

Comment: Thanks so much,now i find the program who always ESTABLISHED many connect by you teach me the way , when i run (find / -name "*programname*"),and then delete they but they always immediately copy to where i delete they with other name and run again.

Comment: There are detailed  instructions, including how to clean it out, in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623596/is-this-file-gcc-sh-in-cron-hourly-malware